# Какие существуют методы анализа текста на принадлежность к определенной тематике?

Tags: статический-анализ, алгоритм, методы

С помощью каких алгоритмов/способов можно отличить текст про кулинарию например от текста про программирование?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Латентно-семантический анализ](http://habrahabr.ru/post/110078/) (**LSA**)

Comment: @Merlin, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Answer (score 3):

Простейший метод - анализ частоты слов в соответствии с тематическими словарями.

Comment: Это очень плохой метод. Наивный Баез работает в некотором роде похоже, но он сам учится на тестовой выборке, а не требует гаданий программиста. И в работе он показывает не просто число "похоже/непохоже", а вероятность принадлежности текста к группе.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой, классический способ - Байесовы классификаторы. Их, например, используют в спам фильтрах. (понятно, что сейчас уже далеко не только их)

Есть **очень** мощная и функциональная библиотека для классификации текстов - [DKPro TC](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-tc/).